# Adding a Computed Attribute to ActiveResource Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activeresource

What I'm trying to do is add an attribute to an activeresource resource that computer based on other attributes created from the servers response.

Further complicating things is that the attributes the computation depends on are part of a has_many association say has_many: items.

What I'd like to happen is when u = User.find(123) is called the items are retrieved and an attribute added to User based on some computation, for example u.blue_item_count.

The new attribute also need to appear when to object is serialized into XML or JSON. For instance u would serialize into {"id":1, "name":"bob", "blue_item_count":21 }.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just define a method on your `User` object that uses the `items` association.  For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items

    def blue_item_count
        items.each do |item|
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I think this should work for @greentea, but can you update to use `ActiveResource::Resource` if it really works, as this is what is asked for?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply unfortunately this doesn't work because in my example the blue_item_count wont show up when the u is serialized into json. I need the value added to activeresources attributes hash that's initially populated from the REST call.

Comment: You can implement your own `to_json`

Comment: @mattforni updating your answer, like @rafb3 proposed, would be helpful for others who land here when searching for `ActiveResource`. One approach that would work is to add the attribute to `@attributes`, like so:
`def blue_item_count
  # previous logic
  attributes[:blue_item_count]
end`